# Average Days between Records by User_ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find the average number of days between records grouped by the `user_id` of the record.

The PK for the table is `eval_id`, so my columns are `eval_id`, `user_id`, and `quality_date`.  The output would be just the `user_id` and average days:

There is no consistent number of records per user, and the average would be one value for all records related to the user.  Trying to find a dynamic approach has so far been unsuccessful.

I am using `SQL Server 2012`, SSMS.

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you wrote the query of your create table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

```
select user_id, datediff(day, min(quality_date), max(quality_date)) / (count(*) - 1.0)
from eval
group by user_id
```

**Edit following Jason's comment:**

```
select user_id, datediff(day, min(quality_date), max(quality_date)) / NULLIF((count(*) - 1.0), 0)
from eval
group by user_id
```

will avoid a divide by zero error if there is only one record for a user. That user will have NULL in the average column.

```
select user_id, 
  case 
    when count(*) = 1 then 1
    else datediff(day, min(quality_date), max(quality_date)) / (count(*) - 1.0)
  end
from eval
group by user_id
```

will also avoid the error, but gives 1 instead of NULL for the affected users.

Comment: My only concern with the above is that you've set up a possible divide by zero condition since you could just have one record. Could get around that with a NULLIF condition on the (count(*) - 1.0) (or a case that defaults the value to 1).

Comment: And to that point @Jason, I did run into that.  I added a 'Having' clause to control it.  Good catch!

Comment: @JasonWhisman is perfectly correct. I've added to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the average by taking the total span and dividing by one minus the number of records.

```
select user_id,
       (case when count(*) > 1
             then datediff(day, min(quality_date), max(quality_date)) / (count(*) - 1.0)
        end) as AvgTimeBetween
from eval
group by user_id;
```

There are harder ways to do the calculation, such as calculating each span (using `lag()` say) and then using the `avg()` function.

Comment: thanks!  I see where you are going.  I tried it and I am getting a "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery".

Comment: @BumpML . . . Gosh, I feel stupid.  The `sum()` is totally unnecessary because the difference is between the `max()` and the `min()`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the feeling that you wanted the average of the diff between two consecutive records for a user. My solution will provide you with that, except if the user only has one record.

```
;WITH dummy_data(evalId, userId, qualityTime)
AS
(
    SELECT 1, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 0, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 2, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 5, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 7, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 10, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 14, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 15, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 8, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 16, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 9, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 20, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 10, 123, DATEADD(DAY, 26, '2012-12-12')

    -- Avg 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 11, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 0, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 12, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 13, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 2, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 14, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 3, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 15, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 4, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 16, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 5, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 17, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 6, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 18, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 7, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 19, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 8, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 20, 124, DATEADD(DAY, 9, '2012-12-12')

    -- Avg 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 21, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 0, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 22, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 2, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 23, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 4, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 24, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 6, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 25, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 8, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 26, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 10, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 27, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 12, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 28, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 14, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 29, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 16, '2012-12-12')
    UNION ALL SELECT 30, 126, DATEADD(DAY, 18, '2012-12-12')

    -- Will not show
    UNION ALL SELECT 31, 127, DATEADD(DAY, 0, '2012-12-12')
)
,eval
AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY qualityTime) AS rowNumber
    FROM    dummy_data
)

SELECT  e1.userId
        ,SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, e1.qualityTime, e2.qualityTime)) * 1.0 / COUNT(e1.qualityTime) AS calculated_average
        ,AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, e1.qualityTime, e2.qualityTime)) AS average
FROM    eval e1
JOIN    eval e2
    ON  e1.userId = e2.userId
    AND e1.rowNumber = e2.rowNumber - 1
GROUP BY e1.userId
```